# Swift, how to pass tableview data to view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I want to be able to pass the data filelocation to my other view controller. I was able to pass it but it only displays one filelocation when displayed on the view controller. Where I am getting multiple from the son and all the cells refer back to that one last one. How can i fix this?
Heres my code:

```
if let filelocation = fileList["urllocation"] as? String
{
    TableData1.append(filelocation)
    fileLocationLabelString = (filelocation)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    selectedFileLocation = fileLocationLabelString

    if(segue.identifier == "detailView") {    
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DisplayWorkViewController
        vc.selectedFileLocation = selectedFileLocation
        vc.selectedLabel = selectedLabel
        print("selectedFileLocation = \(vc.selectedFileLocation)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TableData1 is the array variable and fileLocationLabelString is just a String. In order to get the complete list of locations, you have to pass TableData1 and not fileLocationLabelString

EDIT:

*DisplayWorkViewController*

`var listLocation: Array<String> = [""]`

*current view Controller*

```
if let filelocation = fileList["urllocation"] as? String
{
    TableData1.append(filelocation)
    fileLocationLabelString = (filelocation)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    selectedFileLocation = fileLocationLabelString

    if(segue.identifier == "detailView") {    
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DisplayWorkViewController
        vc.selectedFileLocation = selectedFileLocation
        vc.selectedLabel = selectedLabel
        vc.listLocation = TableData1
        print(vc.listLocation.count)
        print("selectedFileLocation = \(vc.selectedFileLocation)")
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly the same way you are doing for `selectedFileLocation`. Create a array variable in your destination view controller and assign the value of TableData1 to it in your prepareForSegue method.

Comment: can you give me an example how do I assign that to tableData1

Comment: its still displaying the same file let me check my json and let you know